# Jenkins process gets killed when I close the putty session of ec2 instance

Tags: jenkins

I am running jenkins on ec2 instance and my process gets killed when I close the putty session.Is there anyway I could run jenkins even after closing the session?

I run jenkins with

```
java -jar jenkins.war &
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a "nohup" in front of it, like so.

```
nohup java -jar jenkins.war &
```

Edit: To add to that, what you should really do is add it as a service in a supported way for the OS you're running, so that it starts when the instance is booted.